# Select com Sql e Input Dinâmico

Tags: php, html, sql

Estou tentando fazer com que o select abaixo, que puxa dados de um sql quando selecionado a opção, altere o valor no `input` ao lado, também vindo do banco de dados sql.

Qual seria a melhor opção?

Segue o codigo.

```
<tr>
  <td>

    Servico:

  </td>
  <td>
    <select name='servico[]' id="servico[]" style="text-transform:uppercase">
      <?php

    $sql="SELECT * FROM servicos ORDER BY nome";

    $resultado=mysql_query ($sql) or die ("Problema na lista!");

    while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array ($resultado))

    {

    $id=$linha["id"];
    $cliente=$linha["nome"];

    ?>
        <option>
          <?=$cliente?>
        </option>
        <?
    }
    ?>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>

    Valor:

    <input name="valor[]" type="text" id="valor[]" size="6">
  </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Não entendi. Você que que, ao selecionar itens no `<select />`, eles aparecem no `<input />`? Tipo, separados por vírgula, algo assim?

Comment: eles vem dinamicamente por sql, preenchem o select. Mas cada select deste, é um serviço, que contem um valor ($). queria que este valor aparecesse no input quando trocasse o serviço nas opções do select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para melhor atender a sua necessidade, ou seja, recuperar o valor de acordo com o produto selecionado no campo `select` vou apresentar a seguinte solução:

1. Fazer com que quando o valor do `select` for alterado, seja criado um evento que dispare uma requisição que retorne o valor do produto em formato JSON.

Segue abordagem:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM servicos ORDER BY nome";
$resultado = mysql_query ($sql) or die ("Problema na lista!");
?>
<select name='servico' id="idservico" style="text-transform:uppercase">
    <option value=''> Selecione</option>
    <?php while ($servico = mysql_fetch_object($resultado)): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $servico->id?>"> <?php echo $servico->nome?> </option>
    <?php endwhile ?>
</select>
<br />
<input name="valor" type="text" id="idvalor" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // altera valor do campo
    function alteraValorCampo() {
        var idservico = $( "#idservico" ).val();

         var data = {
          "action": "obtervalor",
          "idservico" : idservico
        };
        data = "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "obtemvalor.php",
          data: data,
          success: function(data) {
            $("#idvalor").val(data.valor);
          }
        });
        return false;
    }

    $( "#idservico" ).change( alteraValorCampo );
    alteraValorCampo();
});
</script>
```

Agora, vamos criar o arquivo `obtemvalor.php` que será responsável por recuperar o valor do produto selecionado no campo `select`.

```
<?php
if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checa se valor existe
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    $id = $_POST['idservico'];
    switch($action) {
      case "obtervalor": obter_valor_servico($id);
      break;
    }
  }
}

//Funcao que checa se a requisicao ajax e valida.
function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function obter_valor_servico($id){
    $sql = "SELECT id, valor FROM servicos WHERE id = ".intval($id);
    $resultado = mysql_query ($sql) or die ("Problema na lista!");

    $linha = mysql_fetch_object($resultado);

    echo json_encode($linha);
}
?>
```

Dessa forma, sempre que houver a seleção de um serviço, o campo valor receberá o valor do mesmo.

Tecnologias utilizadas para solução: [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) e [AJAX](https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/).

Comment: Fiz como acima, porem ele resulta no mesmo nome do serviço, e não no campo valor que está na mesma linha no registro no sql.

Comment: Você que que apareça o preço do produto no campo valor?

Comment: Veja se agora atende sua necessidade. Se atender, peço que qualifique a resposta. Por favor!

Comment: Ola, obrigado por entender minha necessidade. Entretanto continua sem voltar valores no campo valor, mesmo eu setando as configurações do banco de dados nos arquivos.

Comment: Favor, testar novamente! Fiz as correções e em seguida realizei testes aqui e funcionou.

Comment: deu certo o// Muito obrigado!

Comment: Poxa, bacana! Fico feliz. Pô mano, dê um voto positivo aí pra nós. Heehee